# storing serialized objects to disk instead of using a database

Tags: object, serialization, storage

I'm building a small application and I'd rather not have the expense (hosting, hassle) of a database. I'm thinking of just writing a class (call it Settings) for each user, and serializing it to disk as xml.

When a user logs in, I'll deserialize the xml back into List, scroll through until I find the user I need, and then I've got everything I need.

I suppose I can wrap it all in a Singleton if I need to.

I'm imagining this would be rather crummy for a big application, but we're talking about 100 hits a day kind of stuff.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really think that you will need more time to setup the DB, compared to implementing your file-based solution? I would be surprised, actually and I would much rather go the DB way.